# Proving the limit of $\frac{n!}{10^{n}}$ using definitions

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, self-learning

$\cdot \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{10^n} = \frac{10!}{10^{10}} * (\frac{n!}{10^n})$ for all $n \ge 11$

So we must find $N(M)$ such that $\lvert \frac{10!}{10^{10}} * (\frac{n!}{10^n}) \rvert = \frac{10!}{10^{10}} * (\frac{n}{10})< M$, $\forall n>N$

So $\frac{10!}{10^{10}} < \frac{10}{n} * M (\forall n\ge 11)$

Therefore $\frac{1}{M} *\frac{9!}{10^{10}}< n $

And my function can be max{$11,\frac{1}{M} *\frac{9!}{10^{10}} $}?

Comment: The limit evaluation is not correct.  Do you mean to say that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} {n!\over 10^n}=\infty$$?

Comment: @abiessu yes, my evaluation was just to simplify the limit

Comment: The very first line is nonsense: limit (a number) = sequence (depends on $n$). Try to be more careful in writing for others to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you write
$$
\lim_n\frac{n!}{10^n}=\frac{10!}{10^{10}}\times\frac{n!}{10^n},\quad \forall n\geq 11.
$$
A simple and related approach to this problem is as follows: define $\delta=\frac{10!}{10^{10}}>0$. Note also that for $n\geq 11$,
$$
\frac{11\times 12\times \cdots \times n}{10^{n-10}}\geq 1.1^{n-10}.
$$
This suggests that for any given $M>0$, if we let $N=\max\{11,10+\frac{\log(M/\delta)}{\log 1.1}\}$, then for $n\geq N$,
$$
\frac{n!}{10!}=\delta\times\frac{11\times 12\times \cdots \times n}{10^{n-10}} \geq\delta (1.1)^{n-10}>\delta(1.1)^{\frac{\log(M/\delta)}{\log 1.1}}=M.
$$

---

**Alternative**: *not* using $\log$. Note that: for $n\geq 11$, the Bernoulli's inequality gives
$$
1.1^{n-10}=(1+0.1)^{n-10}\geq 1+\frac{n-10}{10}>\frac{n-10}{10}.
$$
Now pick $N=\max\{11,10+\frac{10M}{\delta}\}$.

Comment: My professor won't let us use logs, so is there any other useful approach that you know of?

Comment: @RyanT.Donnelly See edit.